# Product page layout (variants)

Tags: configurable-product, product-view, product-page

We're considering migrating a site to Magento 1.9x and they have a page that lists variants of the same product on the page - [OS Explorer Map 172](http://www.guidepost.uk.com/shop/acatalog/GUIDEPOST__EXPLORER_172_339.html) and I was wondering how to replicate this on Magento. Configurable product won't work as that just gives you a dropdown of the variants. Thinking maybe of using the list.phtml and filtering somehow. Anyone got a more elegant approach?

An alternative would be to present the product like they do [on Ordnance Survey](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/shop/maps/explorer-map-snowdon.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a own theme and replace / edit the template files for them.
Assignable with "related products" or "upsell products".

Things i would try:

> • Add the products as "related" or "upsell"
>
> • Change the templates to display thoose as wanted
>
> • Profit or failure